# Stuck on First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm taking a first-order logic class and I keep finding myself stuck on proofs that ask for disjunction elimination and then supply additional premises with conjunctions. How can I eliminate negations and conjunctions to get the premises I need to get consistent conclusions in disjunction elimination subproofs? Here's an example of something I'm working on:

(Goal: ~Cube(f))

1.| SameRow(b,f) v SameRow(c,f) v SameRow(d,f)

2.| ~SameRow(c,f)

3.| FrontOf(b,f)

4.| ~(SameRow(d,f) ∧ Cube(f))

5. |SameRow(b,f)
6. | ⊥         Ana Con 3,5
7. |~Cube(f)   ⊥Elim 6

(end subproof)

8. |SameRow(c,f)
9. | ⊥         ⊥Intro 2,8
10. |~Cube(f)   ⊥Elim 9

At this point I'm not sure what to do about the SameRow(d,f) part of the disjunct in premise 1. How do I use ~(SameRow(d,f) ∧ Cube(f)) to derive anything that I can use to reach ~Cube(f) in the last subproof? I get that the sentence is equivalent to ~SameRow(d,f) ∧ ~Cube(f), but I can't see how to get a contradiction from that.

Any help about this problem/strategy in general would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: I don't understand what the premises are. In any case the end of your proof is your goal, so it seems you proved what you wanted.

Comment: The proof's actually not done - I'm stuck in the middle. The premises are sentences 1-4 and then I've written the first two subproofs for the disjunct in premise 1. I'm a little stuck figuring out how to get ~Cube(f) for the SameRow(d,f) disjunct.

Comment: For that bit, assume $\text{Cube}(f)$, then you get $\text{SameRow}(d,f)\land \text{Cube}(f)$.

Comment: Ah, I see! Sometimes it's hard to know what to assume, but that makes so much sense. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If no one answers the question in a reasonable amount of time if would be good if you'd post an answer yourself so this doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to Git Gud for the pointers! I needed to introduce a subproof assuming Cube(f) within the subproof for SameRow(d,f). The complete proof looks like this:

Goal: ~Cube(f)

1.|SameRow(b,f) v SameRow(c,f) v SameRow(d,f)
2.|~SameRow(c,f)
3.|FrontOf(b,f) 
4.|~(SameRow(d,f) ^ Cube(f)) 
5.    |SameRow(b,f) 
6.    |⊥           Ana Con 3,5 
7.   |~Cube(f)    ⊥Elim 6 
(end subproof)
8.   |SameRow(c,f)
9.   |⊥          ⊥Intro 2,8
10.  |~Cube(f)   ⊥Elim 9
(end subproof)
11.   |SameRow(d,f)
12.    |Cube(f)
13.        |SameRow(d,f) ^ Cube(f)    ^Intro 11, 12
14.        |⊥                        ⊥Intro 4, 13
15.     |~Cube(f)                    ~Intro 11-14
16.|~Cube(f)      VElim 1,5-7,8-10,11-14